# can't find the Blender ID add-on sign in

Tags: add-on, blender-id

I have been trying to download the textured brushes add-on from the Blender Cloud. I understand that the download should consist of 2 files, one being a one-time sign in utility for the cloud, the other being the add-on itself. But all I can download is blender_cloud-1.16.addon and this extracts to a single file. Can't find the ID add-on sign in file anywhere.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Hello :). I believe Blender ID is shipped with blender. Justn enable it in preferences > addons and log in.

Comment: Thanks Jachym, but I can't find it there! And all the documentation that I have found indicates that it should be downloaded from the cloud. But I can't find it there either.

Answer (score 1):

The addon is shipped with Blender :). It's called *Blender ID authentication*

1. Enable *Blender ID authentication addon* in *Preferences > Addons*
2. Log In
3. Download and Install [BlenderCloud add-on](https://cloud.blender.org/services) directly from the .zip file (don't unpack anything)

*Here's a screenshot of both Blender Cloud and Blender ID addon in my Blender.*

[image]

Comment: Are you using Blender 2.83, or an earlier version?

Comment: HI Jachym, OK I found it now! Thanks very much for your help!